# Objects on a ground plane lose color saturation (Cycles)

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to render a book with a blue cover which casts shadows on a yellow ground plane. The problem is that the light reflects from the ground plane and makes the book cover look yellowish as well.

[image: yellowish]
(Image scaled and compressed, only to give an idea of what the rendered result looks like).

Here is a render of a similar object which shows the correct color:
[image: correct color]

Here is what I've found out so far:

- Brighter lighting is desirable in this case, but it doesn't correct the color.
- A blue light makes the cover look slightly better, but then the red text becomes bluish as well.

Is there any better way to fix my problem? Also, is it possible to make the cover color a bit more saturated in general? My rendering engine is Cycles, other details will be in the attached Blender file.

[image]

(This is the right file, you might need to rename it to `.blend` to open it)

Cover image (file name: *cover.png*, put it in the folder together with the Blender file):
[image: cover]

Comment: you have uploaded your .blend file wrongly. please reupload the .blend instead of .blend1

Comment: This is the file I have been working on for the past few days - it is up-to-date and opens correctly, except that the cover image doesn't display - I will attach it.

Comment: No. I mean if you hit the download button in stack exchange , you will download .blend1 file which is extra and generated by blender. So you should look for a .blend file is same folder. its format must be .blend.

Comment: @ErfanGames: you can just rename it to .blend - then you can open it

Comment: may i ask why you used shrinkwrap to get your image on the book? why didn't you just use uv editing/unwrap?

Comment: @Chris I just followed a tutorial to add an image (actually, several tutorials I've seen were doing it that way). I was thinking of trying out UV unwrap, but I couldn't figure it out. If you think it is going to affect anything, I will definitely look into it once more.

Comment: If you don't want your ground color effecting your book, you should change your render engine from cycles to evee. in fact its a future of cycles but in some cases its bad.

Comment: @ErfanGames I agree that Eevee works better in this regard, but with it shadows are completely unrealistic, and it's hard to fix. That's why I decided to switch to Cycles

Comment: Hi - the file you posted is a .blend1 file and not .blend - could you post the .blend instead?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett This is not a mistake - the file can be opened just like a regular .blend file. You might need to rename it. Please read the comments above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mixing your (shaded) book cover image with an unshaded version of the same image (this will remove some Diffuse influence, but too much could make the lighting seem unrealistic - use the slider on the mix shader to find the best balance). You can also add a Hue/Saturation node in the chain to boost the colors:

[image: Shade]

Comment: Thank you) I will need some time to figure it out because it goes beyond my knowledge, but I'll get back to you with some results later.

Comment: I found out that I get great results without the HSV node and with Mix Shader Fac = 0.

Comment: That's fine if it works for you - bear in mind that _fac 0_ in this setup means you are only using the top (unshaded) input (the influence of the Principled BSDF is 0). If it works for your scene it's fine, but if you remove all the lights from your scene, you will see that the book is still fully lit, and perhaps glowing a little (unshaded input is handled as a weak emission shader).